# How can I make a specific div with transparent background-color over a div with black background-color

Tags: html, css

How can I make a specific div with transparent background-color over a div with black background-color?

Thanks.

I have tried to make it work with adding another div with transparent but no luck, my code as below

```
.a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.b {
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.c {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 170px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
}​

<div class="a"><img src="http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJW6U/1/

BEFORE
[image]

AFTER
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you need to "clip" part of the area that the black `div` is covering?

Comment: Would you be okay with using a bit of JavaScript?

Comment: That's ok, JavaScript or jQuery are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is even if you do this you're just going to see your semi-black div behind your transparent one, it's not going to "cut out" the div below it.

What about this?

```
.a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*overflow hidden to contain box shadow*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    /*using box-shadow to create background*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50000px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50000px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    /*change height and position as needed*/
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 45px;
    left: 75px;
    z-index: 10;
}​
```

Markup will have to change to the following:

```
 <div class="a">
    <img src="http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg" />
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJW6U/71/

Hope this helps.

Bonus: use something like this to attach .b to the mouse:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.b').css({
       left:  e.pageX -25,
       top:   e.pageY -25
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, but can it be compatible on IE8? Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesYeung Nope, `box-shadow` isn't supported on IE8.

Comment: This method won't work currently, but there are 3 things you can do:

1. Use @Abody97's JS version :)

2. Put a border on .b so it is still visible for graceful degradation.

3. Use CSS3 PIE: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 1):

For a JavaScript solution, check out this jsFiddle: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/X87QV/).

If any part of the code is vague, I'd be glad to explain it. Note that I have tried to improve your HTML and CSS structure a bit -- there's no need to specify `width`s or `height`s anymore.

Here are commented versions of the code, HTML:

```
<div class = "a">
    <img src = "http://www.fox.com/glee/_ugc/images/bios/jayma-mays_small.jpg"/>
    <div class = "b">
    </div>
    <div class = "c">
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.a {
    position: relative; /*to make sure children are positioned relatively to it*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.b {
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; /*fill all of the parent*/
    z-index: 5;
}
.c {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
function clip(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var w = x2 - x1, h = y2 - y1; //find width and height of the clipping area
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("c")[0];
    div.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.fox.com/glee/_ugc/images/bios/jayma-mays_small.jpg')";
    div.style.backgroundPosition = (-x1) + "px " + (-y1) + "px";
    div.style.width = w + "px";
    div.style.height = h + "px";
    div.style.top = y1 + "px";
    div.style.left = x1 + "px";
}
clip(75, 75, 150, 150); //clips from 75, 75 to 150, 150, you can customize it
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great, but can it be compatible on IE8? Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesYeung IE8 doesn't support `opacity`.